# Can I tow an automatic car if the engine is on

Tags: automatic-transmission, towing

Can I tow an automatic car if the engine is on?

Broken down due to low transmission fluid (possibly I am getting a sensor error).

Is it possible to tow the automatic car about 5 miles at a low speed 25 mph?

Are there any risks involved.

Comment: The car is a 2014 Audi A3 1.4 if this helps

Comment: If the fluid is low then there is a risk - get it towed on a flat-bed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As best I can tell, the A3 is a FRONT wheel drive vehicle.  If so, then there is no issues towing it with the rear wheels on the ground.

That assumes, of course, that you are using a towing service that will life the front.  Otherwise, get a towing service that will put the entire vehicle on the bed and move it for you.

No, you should NOT tow an automatic transmission vehicle with the drive wheels on the ground.

Comment: Yah, no flat towing. The OP should be able to use a tow dolly, though ... put the drive wheels up on the dolly and have it.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 why cant you tow it in neutral? It should free wheel? With engine idling it would have power steering and brakes.

Comment: You cannot tow a automatic transmission vehicle on its drive wheels because input from the output shaft will NOT drive the oil pump and lubricate the transmission.

Comment: @SirSwears-a-lot - If the transmission is low on fluid, you run the risk of it not pushing fluid with it running. With that, you are going to burn it up even faster. As jwh20 said without the engine running it gets ugly. Tranny pumps are usually attached to the torque converter and the TC is attached to the engine ... no running engine, no fluid distribution: fried components; more cost to repair.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 What about with the engine on? as OP has asked? Short distance?

Comment: @SirSwears-a-lot - If the transmission is low on fluid (as the OP states) and you leave the engine on, it will either run the transmission further out of fluid and destroy the front pump (doesn't take long), or it will destroy the front pump for lack of fluid. This really isn't a good idea considering the OP's situation, even for a short distance.

Comment: RAC in the UK insisted on towing it. It was towed!